# Memory Usage Issue

Tags: azure, caching, redis

We have observed memory usage graph on Azure Portal for redis cache.
Can someone help? What happened? Why sudden spike in memory usage?

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that is a reporting bug in Azure... I doubt you really used that... I might be able to ping some Azure folks (no guarantees). Enquiring minds demand to know: what is the full number here? (in particular, to compare to well known numbers like max-value of key data widths). I very much doubt that this is a real number for an in-memory database (even clustered).

Comment: @MarcGravell man that would be expensive ;)

Comment: @MichaC you can get bulk discounts for yottabytes, right?

Comment: Looks like you need a small loan of a million dollars...

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should open a support ticket and share your subscription id and cache name.

Comment: @AndyShen we have created ticket already and send query for the memory usage graph also but no response yet.

Comment: What are the two values? Can you get from one to the other by changing a single bit?

Comment: Closing as off-topic; while it is undoubtedly kinda related, this ultimately isn't a programming question - it can't be fixed with code, but rather: is a support ticket with a vendor (Microsoft). It is very interesting though, and that image has made my month!

Comment: Thanks All for quick response and support.